# Deleting a row in pandas dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Scenario:** I have a dataframe with some nan scattered around. It has multiple columns, the ones of interest are "bid" and "ask"

**What I want to do:** I want to remove all rows where the bid column value is nan AND the ask column value is nan.

**Question:** What is the best way to do it?

**What I already tried:**

```
ab_df = ab_df[ab_df.bid != 'nan' and ab_df.ask != 'nan']

ab_df = ab_df[ab_df.bid.empty and ab_df.ask.empty] 

ab_df = ab_df[ab_df.bid.notnull and ab_df.ask.notnull]
```

But none of them work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need vectorized logical operators `&` or `|` (*and* and *or* from python are to compare scalars not for pandas Series), to check nan values, you can use `isnull` and `notnull`:

To *remove all rows where the bid column value is nan AND the ask column value is nan*, keep the opposite:

```
ab_df[ab_df.bid.notnull() | ab_df.ask.notnull()]
```

*Example*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        "bid": [pd.np.nan, 1, 2, pd.np.nan],
        "ask": [pd.np.nan, pd.np.nan, 2, 1]
    })

df[df.bid.notnull() | df.ask.notnull()]

#   ask bid
#1  NaN 1.0
#2  2.0 2.0
#3  1.0 NaN
```

If you need both columns to be non missing:

```
df[df.bid.notnull() & df.ask.notnull()]

#   ask bid
#2  2.0 2.0
```

---

Another option using `dropna` by setting the *thresh* parameter:

```
df.dropna(subset=['ask', 'bid'], thresh=1)

#   ask bid
#1  NaN 1.0
#2  2.0 2.0
#3  1.0 NaN

df.dropna(subset=['ask', 'bid'], thresh=2)

#   ask bid
#2  2.0 2.0
```

Comment: In this case, since I want both bid and ask to be nan, should I use &?

Comment: It depends on what you want to keep, if you need both bid and ask to be non missing values, then you'll need `&`.

Comment: Yes, that is the case, I only want to remove if both are nan. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @DGMS89 I think you want the answer as written - test it to be sure, and look at the middle section of my answer where I got it wrong at first! you want to REMOVE if both are null, which means KEEP if either isn't null.

Answer (score 2):

```
ab_df = ab_df.loc[~ab_df.bid.isnull() | ~ab_df.ask.isnull()]
```

all this time I've been usign that because i convinced myself that `.notnull()` didn't exist. TIL.

```
ab_df = ab_df.loc[ab_df.bid.notnull() | ab_df.ask.notnull()]
```

The key is `&` rather than `and` and `|` rather than `or`

I made a mistake earlier using `&` - this is wrong because you want either bid isn't null OR ask isn't null, using and would give you only the rows where both are not null.

I think you can `ab_df.dropna()` as well, but i'll have to look it up

EDIT

oddly `df.dropna()` doesn't seem to support dropping based on NAs in a specific column. I would have thought it did.

based on the other answer I now see it does. It's friday afternoon, ok?

Comment: Yeah I know the friday feeling. Been working on this code for 2 weeks, and got almost no progress. I am about to shoryuken my pc to the stratosphere.